# Unknown opcode ^ in asm instruction

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm using Intel compiler on Linux for the following small test case.

```
void a() {
    __asm xor rax,rax
}

void b() {
    b();
}
```

If compile with icpc I get an error.
`a_s.c(3): (col. 22) error: Unknown opcode ^ in asm instruction.`

If compile with icc, then everything is OK. So it is somehow connected to C++ dialect.

If I cover `xor rax,rax` with `{ }` (i.e `{xor rax,rax}`), then icpc starts to compile without issue.

If I try to use g++ (I do not how it is correct for MS-style asm) I also see a complaint about "^" token.

```
bash-3.2$ g++ a_s.c
a_s.c: In function 'void a()':
a_s.c:3: error: expected `(' before '^' token
a_s.c:3: error: expected primary-expression before '^' token
```

So is this a bug in Intel C++ compiler or some C++ standard forbids using inline asm such way without braces?

Thank you.

Comment: `xor` in C++ is pretty much literally `^`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/xor

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a nasty macro in one of your headers, e.g. `#define xor ^` ?

Comment: For example, `iso646.h` will have a `#define xor ^` in it.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, It shouldn't in C++, only C. *Identifiers that are keywords or operators in C++shall not be defined as macros in C++standard library headers*  with a note *In particular, including the standard header<iso646.h>or<ciso646>has no effect*

Comment: @chris: even if the standard forbids it, it still might affect C++. I know it normally does for MSVC (but not GCC).  I don't know about Intel's compiler.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, True, I forgot MSVC did that.